# Apache Derby DB not working when I close NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

I am a beginner to Java and Databases. 
Recently, i have been developing a Java Application where I am using `derby` database. When I start NetBeans and run the project it works fine. But when I close the IDE and run the .JAR file it does not not work. Can anybody tell me the reason behind it?

Comment: If you find any answer that has solved your problem or at least helped you out to bring close to the solution then you must and should **accept or up-vote** the particular answer post here in SO.

Answer (score 2):

Netbeans is running Apache Derby for you in a networked mode, and your application is connecting to it. When netbeans is not running, then the database is not running either, so it's not available to your application.

If you want your application to run w/o a being able to reach a database over a network, your application must be changed to run Derby in embedded mode.

If you want your application to run connected to a networked version of Derby, you will need to arrange to run Derby somewhere that your application can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will not run as when you connect to the `localhost:1527` port, it opens in Network mode (more exactly a client-server mode) which means : it will only work when the IDE is running which runs the Apache Derby DB Server and all other services.

You should try running it in `Embedded` Mode which will run your database even if you are not establishing a connection to the Derby server.

In a **more simpler** way I would say that **it acts just like a file to your java executable, which manipulates data based on the schema you provide**. You must try this fantastic and simple way [Java, NetBeans and Derby Embedded](http://aparna-java.blogspot.in/2011/11/good-day-all.html). It will server your purpose. But before you begin `Embedded` you must add [`derby.jar`](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html) file to your classpath.

Thanks!! Hope it helps