# Netbeans Derby database doesn't work when netbeans is closed

Tags: java, database, netbeans, derby

I have created a java program with an `client/server` derby database, but when I created a jar file and close netbeans then run the jar file an exception shows up (I want to use this program on another computer):

> java.sql.sqlnontransientconnectionexception java.net.connectexception error connecting to server localhost on port 1527

I searched for same questions but i couldn't find a clear solution.

Comment: You need to write code to connect to the database. If you just create a database without coding and connect it, it won't work when the IDE is closed.

Comment: You had netbeans create it for you. Which means you didn't code in anything to start or stop the server presumably. I would start there. Find the code that starts the derby server so it can run outside of netbeans.

Comment: okay but what type of code? explain please

Comment: I posted the answer below.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30784241/apache-derby-db-not-working-when-i-close-netbeans-ide?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You have to start the derby server. When you use Netbeans builtins it will do it for you to save time, but if you aren't running it in the IDE you have to start it  yourself.

```
NetworkServerControl serverControl = new NetworkServerControl(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"),1527)

serverControl.shutdown();
```

The documentation is here. 
http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/adminguide/tadminconfig814963.html